# Is there a Spring Batch 3 Upgrade Script for MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I haven't seen a script to do the DDL modification necessary to go from Spring Batch 2 -> 3 in MySQL. Curious if one exists?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After running a quick comparison of the schemas, these appear to be the changes for upgrading from Spring Batch 2.2.7.RELEASE -> 3.0.1.RELEASE on MySQL.

```
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` MODIFY COLUMN `EXIT_CODE` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` ADD COLUMN `JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` MODIFY COLUMN `EXIT_CODE` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
```

Comment: Alex - Where you find these ALTER statements? Can you please provide a link for reference ?

Comment: I reverse engineered them.

Comment: Alex - Could you pls help / guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107254/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-table-spring-batch-t ?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who wants to know the `DDL` changes for `postgresql`:

```
ALTER TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION ALTER COLUMN EXIT_CODE TYPE varchar(2500);
ALTER TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION ADD COLUMN JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION ALTER COLUMN EXIT_CODE TYPE varchar(2500);
```

This worked for me when I upgraded from `2.2.7.RELEASE` -> `3.0.7.RELEASE`.

Really surprised there's no migration guide/or scripts, at least that I could find.