# Unknown column 'JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION' in 'field list' while using spring batch 3.0.0 jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Previously i was using batch `spring-batch-core-2.2.0` and `spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.0` but now i want to use `spring-batch-3.0.0` , so i replaced the jars and used `spring-batch-core-3.0.0` , `spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.0`, `spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE` and `javax.batch-api-1.`0.

But now i m getting the error::

> "bad SQL grammar [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID,
>   JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE,
>   EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED,
>   JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];
>   nested exception is
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION' in 'field list'"

I do not want to delete previous data which is generated by spring batch.

Comment: please provide your code so that we can better determine what the fault is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database tables used internally by spring batch have changed.

Check out the answer to this question: [Is there a Spring Batch 3 Upgrade Script for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044725/is-there-a-spring-batch-3-upgrade-script-for-mysql)

This provides the DDL for upgrading the tables in mysql. Depending on your database you might have to make some minor changes.