# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'spring_batch_tutorial.batch_job_execution_params' doesn't exist - Spring Batch

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am working on Spring MVC+ Spring Batch example, I'm developing an application from link: https://github.com/krams915/spring-batch-tutorial and I was able to successfully deploy the application, but when I click via application I see following error comes. ## Heading ##I've uploaded my code at: **https://github.com/test512/spring-batch-krams-tutorial/tree/master/spring-batch-krams-tutorial**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'spring_batch_tutorial.batch_job_execution_params' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1392)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:692)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:741)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:751)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.getJobParameters(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:385)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:415)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:396)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:697)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:781)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.findJobExecutions(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getStepExecutionCount(SimpleJobRepository.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getStepExecutionCount(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.isStepRestart(JobFlowExecutor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-08-23 22:42:34.130 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG SqlUtils - Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: 42S02; errorCode: 1146]
```

**schema-mysql.sql**

```
-- Autogenerated: do not edit this file

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,  
    VERSION BIGINT ,  
    JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  (
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    VERSION BIGINT  ,  
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CREATE_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
    START_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL , 
    END_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
    STATUS VARCHAR(10) ,
    EXIT_CODE VARCHAR(100) ,
    EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500) ,
    LAST_UPDATED DATETIME,
    constraint JOB_INST_EXEC_FK foreign key (JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_PARAMS  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    TYPE_CD VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
    KEY_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    STRING_VAL VARCHAR(250) , 
    DATE_VAL DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
    LONG_VAL BIGINT ,
    DOUBLE_VAL DOUBLE PRECISION ,
    constraint JOB_INST_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION  (
    STEP_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL,  
    STEP_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    START_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL , 
    END_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,  
    STATUS VARCHAR(10) ,
    COMMIT_COUNT BIGINT , 
    READ_COUNT BIGINT ,
    FILTER_COUNT BIGINT ,
    WRITE_COUNT BIGINT ,
    READ_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
    WRITE_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
    PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
    ROLLBACK_COUNT BIGINT , 
    EXIT_CODE VARCHAR(100) ,
    EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500) ,
    LAST_UPDATED DATETIME, 
    JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION VARCHAR(100),
    constraint JOB_EXEC_STEP_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT  (
    STEP_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
    SERIALIZED_CONTEXT TEXT , 
    constraint STEP_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (STEP_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION(STEP_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT  (
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
    SERIALIZED_CONTEXT TEXT , 
    constraint JOB_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID BIGINT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MYISAM;
INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID BIGINT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MYISAM;
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_SEQ (ID BIGINT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MYISAM;
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_SEQ values(0);


ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` MODIFY COLUMN `EXIT_CODE` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` ADD COLUMN `JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` MODIFY COLUMN `EXIT_CODE` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springbatch.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</springbatch.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
        <cglib.version>3.2.4</cglib.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.10.2.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <hibernate.entitymanager.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version>
        <javassist.version>3.18.1-GA</javassist.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.39</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5-pre8</c3p0.version>
        <querydsl.version>3.7.4</querydsl.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.21</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Web and Web MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring TX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring OXM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Aspect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate and JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ComboPooledDataSource -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- A seamless aspect-oriented extension to the Java programming language -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor (parser, generator) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging, slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP API, JSTL, Standard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing Framework mockito all, Junit, Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Other codes file using as it is. Please help.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.krams" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

    <!-- Import extra configuration -->
    <import resource="trace-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-data.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-batch.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-batch-job1.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-batch-job2.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-batch-job3.xml"/>

    <bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

</beans>
```

**spring-batch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <bean id="userWriter" class="org.krams.batch.UserItemWriter"/>
    <bean id="roleWriter" class="org.krams.batch.RoleItemWriter"/>  

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher"
        p:jobRepository-ref="jobRepository" 
        p:taskExecutor-ref="taskExecutor"/>

    <!-- 4.3. Configuring a JobLauncher asynchronously -->
    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

    <!-- http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?59779-Spring-Batch-1-1-2-Standard-JPA-does-not-support-custom-isolation-levels-use-a-sp -->
    <!-- <job-repository id="jobRepository" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
        data-source="jpaDataSource" 
        isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        table-prefix="BATCH_"
        max-varchar-length="100" /> -->

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="jpaDataSource" />
         <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
         <property name="databaseType" value="MYSQL" />
         <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_"/>
         <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
    </bean>  

    <!-- <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
        p:dataSource-ref="jpaDataSource" /> -->

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jpaDataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**spring-data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.krams.repository" />

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
    <bean id="jpaDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClass" value="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${app.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${app.jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${app.jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory --> 
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jpaDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateVendor" />
        <!-- <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property> -->
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Specify our ORM vendor -->
    <bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        <!-- <property name="database" value="MYSQL" /> -->
    </bean>

     <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**spring-batch-job1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <job id="batchJob1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="userload1" next="roleLoad1">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="userFileItemReader1" writer="userWriter" commit-interval="${job.commit.interval}" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
        <step id="roleLoad1">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="roleFileItemReader1" writer="roleWriter" commit-interval="${job.commit.interval}" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>

    <bean id="userFileItemReader1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:${user1.file.name}" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="username,firstName,lastName,password" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="org.krams.batch.UserFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="roleFileItemReader1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:${role1.file.name}" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="username,role" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="org.krams.batch.RoleFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Comment: Have you configured your repository's prefix?

Comment: Hi Michael Minella - Sir Could you please guide/ provide solution on this issue? As you're creator of 'Spring Batch', so expecting positive response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per link: https://harinathreddyyanamala.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/spring-batch-upgrade-from-2-1-7-to-2-2-7/comment-page-1/#comment-22

```
1) Upgrade Spring Batch and Spring Batch test from 2.1.7 to 2.2.7 Release. change the maven dependency version to 2.2.7
2) Upgraded my Spring to 3.2.8 Release to have the compatability with Batch version
3) In 2.2.7 Release, there is a change in Spring Batch Meta-Data Schema. BATCH_JOB_PARAMS table is dropped and a new table BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS 
is added. All the JOB PARAMS are inserted to BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS.
```

Also as per link: [Is there a Spring Batch 3 Upgrade Script for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044725/is-there-a-spring-batch-3-upgrade-script-for-mysql/25044930?noredirect=1#comment65611252_25044930) you need to make the following changes in or rather use below file:

```
-- Autogenerated: do not edit this file

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,  
    VERSION BIGINT ,  
    JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  (
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    VERSION BIGINT  ,  
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CREATE_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
    START_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL , 
    END_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
    STATUS VARCHAR(10) ,
    EXIT_CODE VARCHAR(100) ,
    EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500) ,
    LAST_UPDATED DATETIME,
    constraint JOB_INST_EXEC_FK foreign key (JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_PARAMS  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    TYPE_CD VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
    KEY_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    STRING_VAL VARCHAR(250) , 
    DATE_VAL DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
    LONG_VAL BIGINT ,
    DOUBLE_VAL DOUBLE PRECISION ,
    constraint JOB_INST_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS  (
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    TYPE_CD VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
    KEY_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    STRING_VAL VARCHAR(250) ,
    DATE_VAL DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
    LONG_VAL BIGINT ,
    DOUBLE_VAL DOUBLE PRECISION ,
    IDENTIFYING CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
    constraint JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;




CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION  (
    STEP_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL,  
    STEP_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    START_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL , 
    END_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,  
    STATUS VARCHAR(10) ,
    COMMIT_COUNT BIGINT , 
    READ_COUNT BIGINT ,
    FILTER_COUNT BIGINT ,
    WRITE_COUNT BIGINT ,
    READ_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
    WRITE_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
    PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
    ROLLBACK_COUNT BIGINT , 
    EXIT_CODE VARCHAR(100) ,
    EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500) ,
    LAST_UPDATED DATETIME, 
    JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION VARCHAR(100),
    constraint JOB_EXEC_STEP_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT  (
    STEP_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
    SERIALIZED_CONTEXT TEXT , 
    constraint STEP_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (STEP_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION(STEP_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT  (
    JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
    SERIALIZED_CONTEXT TEXT , 
    constraint JOB_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
    references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID BIGINT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MYISAM;
INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID BIGINT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MYISAM;
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_SEQ (ID BIGINT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MYISAM;
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_SEQ values(0);

-- insert script that 'copies' existing batch_job_params to batch_job_execution_params
-- sets new params to identifying ones
-- verified on h2, 

INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS 
    ( JOB_EXECUTION_ID , TYPE_CD, KEY_NAME, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING )
SELECT 
    JE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID , JP.TYPE_CD , JP.KEY_NAME , JP.STRING_VAL , JP.DATE_VAL , JP.LONG_VAL , JP.DOUBLE_VAL , 'Y' 
FROM 
    BATCH_JOB_PARAMS JP,BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION JE
WHERE 
    JP.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = JE.JOB_INSTANCE_ID;


ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` MODIFY COLUMN `EXIT_CODE` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` ADD COLUMN `JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` MODIFY COLUMN `EXIT_CODE` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD COLUMN `UNIQUE_KEY` char(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ` ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_KEY_UN` (`UNIQUE_KEY`);
```

This `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS` table has to be created as per link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/migration/migration-mysql.sql

Now in order to create `auto-increment` values for Role and User table in `mysql` you need to modify the model like below:

```
@Entity(name="role")
public class Role {
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  // Should never use GenerationType.AUTO or @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
   ....
```

And

```
@Entity(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
     ..........
}
```

I run this code locally and can see data saving into the Role and User table.

```
mysql> select * from role;
+----+------+---------+
| id | role | user_id |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 |    1 |       1 |
|  2 |    2 |       2 |
|  3 |    1 |       3 |
|  4 |    1 |       4 |
|  5 |    2 |       5 |
|  6 |    1 |       6 |
|  7 |    1 |       7 |
|  8 |    2 |       8 |
|  9 |    1 |       9 |
| 10 |    2 |      10 |
+----+------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user;
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| id | firstName | lastName | password  | username |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | John      | Smith    | 12345678  | john     |
|  2 | Jane      | Adams    | abcdefgh  | jane     |
|  3 | Mike      | Myers    | zxcvxvdf  | mike     |
|  4 | Ryan      | Girardi  | cvbvhtrn3 | ryang    |
|  5 | Mary      | Poppins  | xcty68xgf | maryp    |
|  6 | Dian      | Cruised  | hgfhrt556 | dianc    |
|  7 | Ralph     | Watson   | 43545dfge | ralph    |
|  8 | Kyle      | Smith    | 43sdtsdf4 | kyle     |
|  9 | Elaine    | Rogers   | 4z456gff  | elaine   |
| 10 | Mark      | Johnson  | 1683fjjs  | mark     |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[image]